# What precisely did ibn Qayyim say regarding a husband engaging his wife in housework?

Tags: women, husband-wife, fatwa-explanation

From [an IslamWeb fatwa](http://www.islamweb.net/en/article/139500/):

> Ibn Qayyim cited that marriage contract enables a husband to enjoy his wife; it does not enable him to engage her in housework.  [He] said that the above narrations describe only the high moral standards.

I'm guessing this refers to [Ibn Qayyim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Qayyim_al-Jawziyya), but I'm not too sure.  In any case, I'm seeking a more precise description of what Al-Qayyim said, rather than the above paraphrasing, and what evidence this is based on.

**Question**: What precisely did ibn Qayyim say regarding a husband engaging his wife in housework?

Unfortunately, the IslamWeb fatwa does not give a specific reference, so I don't know where to look.  And I'm guessing I couldn't read it even if I did know (it may be in one of links at the bottom of the Wikipedia page).

Comment: [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/1704) seems to mention it more, however i couldn't find any references:  "Ibn al-Qayyim said, concerning the story of Asma’: “When the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) saw Asma’ with the date pits on her head, and her husband al-Zubayr was with her, he did not tell him that she did not have to serve him, or that this was unfair to her. He approved of her serving him and of all the women among the Sahaabah helping their husbands. This is a matter concerning which there is no doubt.”"